# Дублируется возвращаемое значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вызове функция возвращает значения, дублируя его с предыдущим

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
new_news = []
news = []
new_li =[]
url = 'https://donetskafisha.ru/kurs-dollara-i-grivny-v-dnr/'
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
          }
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
news = soup.findAll('div', class_='uncode_text_column')
string = ''

def valut(string = None):
    if string is None:
        string = '' 
        for i in range(len(news)):
            if news[i].find('span', class_='uk-text-large') is not None:
                new_news.append(news[i].text)
        for i in range(len(new_news)):
            new_li.append(new_news[i].strip())
            string='\n'.join(new_li)
    return string
print(valut())
string = ''
print(valut())
```

[image: первый вызов дает желаемый результат,второй вызов функции добовляет строку к предыдущей]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите

```
new_news = []
new_li = []
```

В функцию

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://donetskafisha.ru/kurs-dollara-i-grivny-v-dnr/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
news = soup.find_all('div', class_='uncode_text_column')


def valut():
    new_news = []
    new_li = []
    string = ''
    for i in range(len(news)):
        if news[i].find('span', class_='uk-text-large') is not None:
            new_news.append(news[i].text)
    for i in range(len(new_news)):
        new_li.append(new_news[i].strip())
        string = '\n'.join(new_li)
    return string


print(valut())
print('-' * 50)
print(valut())
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь

```py
news = soup.findAll('div', class_='uncode_text_column')
string = ''
def valut(string = None):
```

Уберите

```py
string = ''
```

и уберите

```py
if string is None:
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто уберите в конце кода это:

```
string = ''
print(valut)
```

И еще функции лучше объявлять в начале кода, сразу после импортов.
Должно получиться так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def valut(string = None):
    if string is None:
        string = '' 
        for i in range(len(news)):
            if news[i].find('span', class_='uk-text-large') is not None:
                new_news.append(news[i].text)
        for i in range(len(new_news)):
            new_li.append(new_news[i].strip())
            string='\n'.join(new_li)
    return string

new_news = []
news = []
new_li =[]

url = 'https://donetskafisha.ru/kurs-dollara-i-grivny-v-dnr/'
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
          }
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
news = soup.findAll('div', class_='uncode_text_column')

print(valut())
```